# SQL Server: Can I save binary data in an nvarchar column?

Tags: sql-server

I know you can convert `binary data` to `nvarchar` and save in an `nvarchar` column, and then convert it back to `binary` when retrieving it. Will this work correctly all the time to give you your original `binary` data? Or could something get messed up in the translation?

I am asking because we have a `nvarchar` column that saves passwords in plain text. I would like this to change to saving the PWs in encrypted text. If I use the function `EncryptByPassPhrase`, it return `varbinary`. I am wondering if I can just convert the output from `EncryptByPassPhrase` to `nvarchar` and save in the same Password column. This would be easier than creating a new column of type `varbinary` to save the encrypted PW.

So I am proposing that I convert the current passwords like this:

```
UPDATE Users 
SET Password = CONVERT(nvarchar(200), EncryptByPassPhrase('whatever', Password))
```

Then I would decrypt and retrieve the PW like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(200), DecryptByPassPhrase('whatever', Password)) AS PW 
FROM Users
```

Will this always work correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt the passwords, you should hash them, and compare results of the hash.

Comment: Ditto, you shouldn't encrypt the passwords, you should hash them with a salt, and compare results of the hash. And binary data in SQL Server belongs to [`VARBINARY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) columns, not NVARCHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring whether or not this is a good idea the following query seems to indicate that all two byte combinations round trip correctly.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT 
      TOP 65536 CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 32769 AS SMALLINT) RN
FROM master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2
), T2 AS 
(
SELECT CAST(CAST(RN AS BINARY(2)) AS NCHAR(1)) AS NC,
       RN
FROM T1 
)
SELECT *
FROM T2 
WHERE CAST(CAST(NC AS BINARY(2)) AS SMALLINT) <> RN
```